# dir-300 router is able to block any website, but not Facebook

Tags: web-filtering, network-traffic, traffic-filtering, dir-300

I'm trying to block the access to certain websites using the **Website Filter** section from Dlink DIR-300 Admin (Firmware 2.14, Hardware Bx which is the latest).

It works for any keyword, except for facebook.

I can access www.facebook.com, but I can't access the URLs that contain facebook.com in their URL, but have different domain. (ie www.randomname.com/facebook.com).

What I've tried:

- to restart the router after I added the settings
- ipconfig /flushdns
- tests from different browsers
- clear browser cache

So how can I really block facebook using this solution?

**Update**
I could block the access to the mobile version (m.facebook.com), via http. However, when this is accessed via https, then facebook is accessible. The problem is the admin interface doesn't allow me to explicitly set this entry https://www.facebook.com.

I just realized the same problem is with YouTube which is also using the https protocol. I tried with other websites that use both HTTP and HTTPS. **The HTTP pages are blocked, but not the HTTPS pages.**

[image: DIR-300 Website Filter - block facebook]

Comment: A firmware update solved a similar problem on that router for [this person](http://www.techspot.com/community/topics/why-doesnt-my-dir-300-routers-parental-control-work.114261/). Check if yours is up-to-date.

Comment: I mentioned is the latest firmware. I updated it before posting this question.

Comment: Does it make any difference if you force non-SSL  e.g. **http**://www.facebook.com/ ?

Comment: http : //www.facebook.com/ - this input is not allowed (no / in input)

Comment: Actually I could add http : //www.facebook.com (without the last /)

Comment: But it doesn't allow me to add https ://www.facebook.com (the https)

Comment: I tested http:/ /www.facebook.com it with Fiddler and I get 504 response. Which is OK, but the browsers are redirecting to https.